# What is the purpose of carry-in in full adder? If carry in equals carry out of previous adder, then I have question

Tags: adder

[image]

In 5th row carry out is 0 then why is carry-in equal to 1 in next adder?

Comment: This is not for the next adder. It is for the same adder. It has 3 inputs and two outputs. So yes, carry out of one adder is going into the carry-in of the next one (for the "ripple" adder topology)

Comment: Similar but not exactly a duplicate.... [What is the purpose of a “carry in”?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/181439/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-carry-in/181444)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at a truth table for a single full adder. The table gives the outputs (Cout and Sum) from the inputs (A, B and Cin).

Comment: Thanks. I got what you are saying.